# How to create a byte array alphabet from a substitution string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I need to code a substitution cipher encryptor. However, I can't figure out how to create an alphabet from the pass key to match the normal alphabet in order to generate my encrypted message

It should gives something like so

```
String passphrase = "mobile";
byte[] expected = {'m', 'o', 'b', 'i', 'l', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f' ...};
```

How could I code a function that return the expected alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a `char` array, by the way. If you really don't want a char array just cast everything to byte.

```
static char[] generateExpected(String passphrase) {
    char[] expected = new char[passphrase.length() + 26];

    passphrase.getChars(0, passphrase.length(), expected, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        expected[i + passphrase.length()] = (char) ('a' + i);
    }

    return expected;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for the sake of the program, I need to use bytes. And the thing is that I need to substitute the the pass phrase from the actual alphabet. So the expected alphabet still has a size of 26. For example, if the passphrase is 'xyz', the expected outcome should be 'xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'